# Django how to use url pk value inside the GCBV (generic classbase view)

Tags: python, django

I am designing generic class base view inside which i want to use the value of pk (primary key) from URL pattern how can i do it?

I have tried view base solution using two parameter (request, pk). But how can it done using `gcbv` post method.

Django URL pattern

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/add_product/$', views.AddProduct.as_view(), name='add_product')
```

**views.py**

```
class AddProduct (LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login_user'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    model = Product
    template_name = 'shopsurfer/add_product.html'
    fields = ['name', 'category', 'lot', 'specs', 'price', 'product_logo']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        pk = ***here want pk from url***
        object.shop = get_object_or_404(Shop, pk=pk)
        object.save()
        return super(AddProduct, self).form_valid(form)
```

I want to store the pk value inside the variable PK which is declared inside the AddProduct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inside the kwargs

```
 pk = self.kwargs['pk']
```

Comment: hi, one more question here how can you tell it's in kwargs ?